# How can I automatically trigger an enter key press event after a certain action is executed?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm writing some unit test in my web apps and I want to automatically trigger an <kbd>Enter</kbd> key pressed event from my page after for example a download to text file button was clicked. How can i do this in jQuery or Javascript?

Comment: you need to trigger the ENTER key pressed after mouse click event?

Comment: you got the answer to it

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1. Create a variable that tells us if the user has clicked your button.

   ```
   var clicked = false;
   ```
2. Add an event listener to your button, so that when the user clicks on it, the `clicked` variable will become `true`.

   ```
   myButton.addEventListener('click', function(){
     clicked = true;
   });
   ```
3. Add a `keypress` event listener:

   ```
   document.addEventListener('keypress', function(e) {
     // `e` is the event
   });
   ```
4. Inside that event listener, check if the user clicked previously

   ```
   if(clicked) {
     // ...
   }
   ```
5. If (s)he did, check the pressed key. Enter's key code is 13.

   ```
   var keynum = e.keyCode||e.which;
   if(keynum == 13) {
      // ...
   }
   ```
6. If the pressed key was enter, use

   ```
   clicked = false;
   ```

   Otherwise, once the user clicked your button and pressed enter, it wouldn't be necessary to click the button again.
7. After that run your code. For example, this will call function `f` after 2 seconds.

   ```
   setTimeout(f, 2000);
   ```

Live demo

```js
var clicked = false;
document.querySelector('#btn').addEventListener('click', function(){
  clicked = true;
  snippet.log("You clicked the button. `clicked` is now `true`");
});
document.addEventListener('keypress', function(e) {
  if(clicked) {
    var keynum = e.keyCode || e.which;
    if(keynum == 13) {
      clicked = false; 
      snippet.log("`clicked` is now `false`. Waiting 2 seconds...");
      setTimeout(f, 2000);
    }
  }
});
function f() {
  snippet.log("Function `f` executed successfully!");
}
```

```css
#btn {
  border: 3px solid red;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div id="btn">Click me, and then press enter.</div>
<!-- Provides the `snippet` object, see http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/242144/134069 --><script src="http://tjcrowder.github.io/simple-snippets-console/snippet.js"></script>
```

Comment: ill try this one out. can you explain whats happening in that code. I'm not an expert in java script so i don't know window.clicked or window.onclick.

Comment: is it possible to wait for a certain amount of time? i want to trigger it after 2 seconds because I'm waiting for the file download window. :)

Comment: I'm amazed this horrendous old answer of mine received 5 upvotes, it even had unnecessary global variables. Updated it, now the code looks better, at least. But still I'm not convinced it answers the question.

Comment: Dont worry it answers the question. :D

Answer (score 5):

If I get your question right, 
this is what you are looking for

```
<html>
<head>

  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>

  <script type="text/javascript">
      $(document).keydown(function(event){
            if(event.keyCode == 13){                
                alert("keypressed");
            }
        });

function clickevent()
{                
     var e = $.Event("keydown");
     e.which = 13;
     e.keyCode = 13;
     $(document).trigger(e);     
}
</script>

</head>
<body id="thebody">
  <input type="button" onclick="clickevent()" value="click me first">
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Is same is possible through JavaScript?

Comment: This is better used for testing purposes.

Answer (score 2):

If you're talking about automatically entering an <kbd>Enter</kbd> key to trigger a `submit` event, you can use this instead:

```
$("#formID").submit();
```

---

To trigger this event after a button has been pressed, try this:

```
$("#buttonID").click(function() {
    $("#formID").submit(); // submits form
});
```

Comment: i want to trigger it after a button was click. and I'm using hyperlink the <a> tag BTW.

Answer (score 1):

```
$("#txtfield").keyup(function(e) {
 if(e.keyCode == 13) {
  $("#submit").submit();
 }
});
```

Comment: i want to do it after a link was clicked. :)